# Referencing Bibliography with Text (and backref) without printing anything

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I want to link an bibliography entry to a place in the continuous text but without using `\cite` or any variation of this that produces output like the key, name, year etc.
Nevertheless there should be a backreference like "(see page 12)" in the bibliography.
Is there an easy workaround or command?

Background: I am citing some laws like "this is the law ABC [KEY]" where KEY is also the shortened Name of the law and it would produce the same word two times but one with paranthesis. It should be like "this is the law ABC" followed bei something like `\ref{KEY}` and also updating the bibliography.

Currently I am using `\nocite{KEY}` that will not produce a backref.

I'm using `biblatex` with `backend=biber` and `backref=true` and don't want to use other packages.

Comment: It depends on hwo you want it really. You could place a `\label{key}` in the section where you want the referance to go, and then write "This is the law ABC (see page `\pageref{key}`"

Comment: @runartrollet Is this really updating the backref of biblatex? It seems like it's just the usual label-ref-mechanism of latex.

Comment: I don't know if it interacts with the backref mechanism, but perhaps `\notecite` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ig0774 It does indeed interact with the backref mechanism, so I'd say your comment would be very suited as an answer.

Comment: If you can tell us more about the style you use and how you cite laws (that is best done in [an MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) which includes an example bib entry), we might even be able to come up with a cite command that prints the name of the law in the format you'd like to see it.

Comment: This shouldn't be useful, the main fact is linking a bibliography entry to a place in text without printing something but also adding a page reference in the bibliography. But I can add one later tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the BibLaTeX command `\notecite{KEY}` does what you want, i.e., it will create a back-reference, add the citation to your references, but it will not attempt to format a citation in the document itself. `\notecite`'s intended use is for cases where you've included all the necessary details in text but you still want to leverage biblatex's other features, such as this case.

All that said, as @moewe mentioned in the comments, it may be possible to come up with a command that would properly format the laws for you, saving you a bit of typing.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It works just as wanted and intended!